# ASP.NET Core Own middleware component

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to get the second argument from HTTP Context? For example

> localhost:45423/?login=login1/?password=password1

- Here is what I coded but it doesn't work. It always says that I'm not logged even when I inputted the correct login and password

```
public class CheckData
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public CheckData(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var login = context.Request.Query["login"];
            var password = context.Request.Query["password"];
            if(login != "log1" && password != "pass1")
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Sorry, you're not logged");
            }
            else
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
        }
    }
```

P.S: I've began learning ASP.NET Core today, only login works, but not login with password

Comment: What does this mean `but it doesn't work`?

Comment: Wait a minute, gonna edit this

Comment: passing username and password in query parameter is not recommended way of doing login. and you are accessing username and password in middleware it means with each request you need to pass them that's even worse. i don't know from where you got this sample to start with. search for jwt based or basic authentication if you really want to learn auth in asp.net core API

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the query parameters wrongly, For multiple query parameter you should pass like `localhost:45423?login=login1&password=password1`

Comment: when i used this query, it said  it can't load the site

Comment: What error do you get? If you get 404 response, please check if you have a default route for 'localhost:45423/' and check if the server is running and the port.